# How to setup snappy compression for a file using flink job running locally

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, snappy

```
native snappy library not available: this version of lib hadoop was built without snappy support.
```

What are all the mandatory files need to be avaiable in hadoo libe folder.

It is saying snappy library is not on the class path

Comment: `snappy-java` should be able to be added as a Maven dependency to your own code, not the Hadoop lib path

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this error message if the shared library (.so) for snappy is not located on the hadoop lib path. If you have the libraries installed in the correct location then you shouldn't see the above error messages.

If you do have the .so installed in the same folder as the hadoop native lib (libhadoop.so), then the above 'error' could be related to the node you are submitting your jobs from (like you say, your job doesn't error and this looks like a message on the client side).

may be youo can refer to https://code.google.com/archive/p/hadoop-snappy/